# I want to map List of objects to a custom object

Tags: java, list, jackson, hashmap

Here is my Custom object

```
public class CustomerDataDTO {

  private Long cust_file_id;

  private String customerName;  

   //getters and setters
  }
```

my code  which is returning list of objects

```
     List<CustomerDataDTO> list = (List<CustomerDataDTO>)(List<? 
     >)internalRepo.getAllCustomerData();
       
  objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(list);
```

which is returning list of objects something like this.

```
     [ [ 379, "ABC" ], [ 380, "BCD" ], [ 381, "DSD" ] ]
```

I want something like this

```
   [ 
   {cust_file_id:379, "customerName":"ABC" }, 
   {cust_file_id:380, "customerName":"BCD" },  
   {cust_file_id:381, "customerName":"DSD" }
   ]
```

Comment: Sounds like you're using `JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY` somewhere.

Comment: ye it an array it is having list of object array

Comment: show us the object mapper initialization

Comment: ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

Comment: Like shmosel said, you sure you don't have a @JsonFormat on your DTO?

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit like json format you are aiming to get, Im sure there are some libraries that could do that for you, but if you just want to do this manually you could just as well

The function you seem to call (Im unfamiliar with) would appear to want to draw the objects as a string, so in this case you could just override the "toString" method:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{cust_file_id:"+cust_file_id+", \"customerName\":\""+customerName+"\" }";
    }
```